# Executing Windows files/events with NW.js (Node Webkit)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, node-webkit

I will start by saying I am far from a JavaScript guy. I work more with HTML and CSS, and "dabble" with JavaScript, as in tweak some code to make JQuery code do what I'd like it to on the front-end.

I am having a bit of an issue with a task I am trying to complete, which has led me to using NW.js (Node Webkit) for the first time.

I am trying to create a 4 button user interface that allows for the following 4 events to occur on click:

```
1. Load a website in a new window
2. Open windows explorer to a specific directory and allow the user to browse
3. Extend Windows Display on a Dual Monitor Setup
4. Clone Windows Display on a Dual Monitor Setup
```

I was originally pretty much finished and achieved my results easily with an HTML Application file - I know, outdated, but it allowed me to work within my skill set and achieve the tasks I needed fairly easily. Problem wa, it wouldn't allow for CSS3 and the website being opened used it, and it pretty much ruined the look of it as a whole. Sooo I needed something new.

I stumbled across NW.js and have started away on that. I've got my package loaded up, my "app" is now launch-able, but the old script isn't working and I am back to square one. I have no idea how to launch executables in Windows using NW.js - it's driving me bonkers!

Below is the code that worked in the HTML Application file (minus the file explorer, which I had yet to get to before realizing it wouldn't work):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
              <title>My HTML App</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
              <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                   function RunPad() {
                   WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                   WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
                   }
                   function RunExtend() {
                   WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                   WshShell.Run("c:/windows/System32/DisplaySwitch.exe /extend", 1, false);
                   }
                   function RunClone() {
                   WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                   WshShell.Run("c:/windows/System32/DisplaySwitch.exe /clone", 1, false);
                   }
                   function RunWebsite() {
                   WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                   WshShell.Run("c:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe", 1, false);
                   }
              </script>
              </head>
                      <body>
                            <div class="container">
                                   <div class="col-1-2"><img src="website.jpg" onclick="RunWebsite();"></div>
                                   <div class="col-1-2"><img src="resources.jpg"></a></div>
                                   <div class="col-1-2"><img src="single_screen.jpg" onclick="RunExtend();"></div>
                                   <div class="col-1-2"><img src="dual_screen.jpg" onclick="RunClone();"></div></div>
                           </div>
                     </body>
     </html>
```

I'm really stuck on this and am not sure which route to take to complete this with NW.js

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveXObject is for IE/Edge only so it won't work under Chromium (used by NW).

What you can do though is create individual Vbs scripts for each of your ActiveXObject functions and call/execute them as required with node.js (supported by NW) in this way...

```
function RunExtProgram(ProgName){

 require('child_process').exec(ProgName,function(error,stdout,stderr){if(error!==null){alert('Unable to launch process:<br><br>'+stderr+'<br><br>'+ProgName);}});

}
```

Usage example:

```
RunExtProgram('C:/test/abc.vbs');
```